# Unable to configure webdriver-manager driver versions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, gulp-protractor

We would like to specify the driver version to the webdriver-manager as the browser type can be configured, so that we can run our tests with an older version if needed.
It seems that currently only the browsers are configurable from outside.

Code from the webdriver_update function of the webdriver-manager file:

```
if (options) {
    if (options.browsers) {
        options.browsers.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            args.push("--" + element);
        });
    }
}
```

As observed the versions are taken from config.json of protractor's base directory

```
var versions = require('../config.json').webdriverVersions;
```

Is there a way or even a workaround to specify a version other than the newest, defined in this file?

Another problem we encountered: Currently the ie driver type (whether is Win32 or 64) is only based on the operating system on which the tests are running. It would be helpful to be able to download a 32-bit version of the IE driver on a 64-bit machine, since the 64-bit version is really slow compared with the 32-bit version. Is there any solution to this?

For now this is how we handle the automatic ie driver download / update:

```
gulp.task('webdriver-update', $.protractor.webdriver_update({
    browsers: ['ie']
}, function(){}));
```

Thank you in advance for the answers!